# Find max sum from database

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to return a person from a database who has the most points during a time period,

My Database table has 3 fileds, Person, Date and number of points,

Points will be added to people individually.

I will have around 30 people in the database and infinite entries in the points table

Can someone help me with a SQL query to return one person with the max number of points.

I had thought of doing this in two steps, 1, fins the sum of points for every person for the selected period but then don't know how to get the person with the most points

EDIT: 
I have the code below to enter the points into the database

```
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO FlightPoints ([Person], [Flight], [Date_Added], [Points], [Reason]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Program.DB_CONNECTION); // add the information into the database
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", cadet[CadetcomboBox.SelectedIndex].ID));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", cadet[CadetcomboBox.SelectedIndex].Flight.ID));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", DateTime.Today));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", PointsnumericUpDown.Value));
        com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("", ReasontextBox.Text));

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also two or more people could in fact have the same total number of points. how could I return all the people with the same top score?

Comment: What's your database/flavor of SQL are you using?  Have you tried anything yet?  If so, what were the results?

Comment: But what if there are several people with the top TOTAL Points, or is the probability of multiple people having the exact same point so remote that you are ok only with the max based on one person.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand correctly, you have two tables so:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PersonName FROM 
(
SELECT  
    PersonName,Points       
FROM
    PersonTable
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                PersonId, SUM(Points) AS Points
            FROM 
                PersonPoint 
            WHERE               
                PointDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
            GROUP BY PersonId               
        ) AS MaxPoints
            ON 
               MaxPoints.PersonId = PersonTable.PersonId
) q
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

> EDIT: Considering that two or more persons can have the same amount of Points the query will be as follow, with the result from bellow you can use a cursor to  select the highest scores:

```
SELECT PersonName FROM 
(
SELECT  
    PersonName,Points       
FROM
    PersonTable
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT
                PersonId, SUM(Points) AS Points
            FROM 
                PersonPoint 
            WHERE               
                PointDate  BETWEEN  @StartDate AND @EndDate
            GROUP BY PersonId               
        ) AS MaxPoints
            ON 
               MaxPoints.PersonId = PersonTable.PersonId
) q
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

Comment: I have one table for the personnel details and one for points.

Comment: OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Person FROM (SELECT Person, Points FROM FlightPoints INNER JOIN (SELECT Person, SUM(Points) AS Points FROM FlightPoints WHERE PointDate <= ? AND PointDate >= ? GROUP BY PersonId) AS MaxPoints ON MaxPoints.PersonId = PersonTable.PersonId) q ORDER BY Points DESC", Program.DB_CONNECTION);
            OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                   
                }
                catch 
                {
                }
            }
            dr.Close();

Comment: ok, that will retrieve user order from highest to lowest accumulated points. Now, as you stated from your EDIT you have to scan the result and return the user or users with highest points. Any problem with the former?

Comment: Im struggling to understand how the SQL command works, could you take a few mins and try to explain for me please? also I don't know how to get the results from the command, I apologise for not knowing much but im learning as we go. Cheers much appreciated.

Comment: What db system are you using?

Comment: Its MS Access database

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 points_person, Sum(points_value)
FROM dbo.points
GROUP BY points_person
ORDER BY Sum(points_value) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in SQL Server, if I got your layout correctly.

```
create table #Points
(
    [Person] varchar(50) not null,
    [Date] DateTime not null,
    [Points] int not null
)

insert into #Points (Person,Date,Points) values ('Hans',GETDATE(),1)
insert into #Points (Person,Date,Points) values ('Hans',GETDATE(),2)
insert into #Points (Person,Date,Points) values ('Hans',GETDATE(),3)
insert into #Points (Person,Date,Points) values ('Hans',GETDATE(),4)
insert into #Points (Person,Date,Points) values ('Fritz',GETDATE(),5)

select top 1 Person, Sum(Points)
from #Points
where Date>='2015-02-26 00:00:00' and Date<='2015-02-26 23:59:59'
group by Person
order by 2 desc

drop table #Points
```